# SQL Compare 2 tables and show only non-matching data

Tags: sql

I know this has been ask quite a few times but I didn't find the answer my problem. I am trying to compare two tables and see which messages has been read by customers (cust_id).

The message_details is split into 4 categories (all, none, single and trade)

It seems to work fine apart from when the condition in message_details is set to all. This will always display even if the customer has read the message.

I hope someone can help.

I have 2 tables

message_details

| id | date | subject | message | condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-18 | Testing | This is a test to all people | all |
| 2 | 2022-01-19 | To all single | This is a single test | single |
| 3 | 2022-01-20 | To all none | This is a None test | none |
| 4 | 2022-01-21 | To all trade | This is a Trade test | trade |
| 5 | 2022-01-19 | To all single | This is a single test 2 | single |
| 6 | 2022-01-19 | To all single | This is a single test 3 | single |

message_read

| id | date | cust_id | message_id | condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-18 | 283 | 1 | read |
| 2 | 2022-01-21 | 283 | 2 | read |
| 3 | 2022-01-18 | 283 | 5 | read |
| 4 | 2022-01-21 | 283 | 6 | read |
| 5 | 2022-01-18 | 211 | 1 | read |
| 6 | 2022-01-21 | 211 | 2 | read |
| 7 | 2022-01-18 | 211 | 5 | read |
| 8 | 2022-01-21 | 211 | 6 | read |
| 9 | 2022-01-18 | 213 | 1 | read |
| 10 | 2022-01-21 | 213 | 2 | read |
| 11 | 2022-01-18 | 213 | 5 | read |
| 12 | 2022-01-21 | 213 | 6 | read |

I am using the following code to check which cust_id has read the message_details.

```
SELECT
id, date, subject, message, condition
FROM
message_details
WHERE
NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT message_id, cust_id FROM message_read
    WHERE message_read.cust_id = '283' AND
    message_read.message_id = message_details.id
)
AND
message_details.condition = 'single' 
OR
message_details.condition = 'all'
```

This seems to work (not sure it's the correct way of doing it) but doesn't hide id 1 from message_details even though cust_id = 283 has read it.

Comment: Does adding `()` around the `OR` portion help? `(message_details.condition = 'single' OR
message_details.condition = 'all')`

Comment: Well something as simple as that. Thank you Paul

Comment: Just on a quick note... Is this the correct way to compare tables? or is there a better/correct way.

Comment: To `a better/correct way` tends to lead into the opinion realm. What you have looks good to me, and I would have used the `NOT EXISTS` route myself. Others that might not realize the exists/not exists syntax/handling might use `LEFT JOINS` to achieve the same results. If the `EXPLAIN` of that query looks good, then what you have now should be fine.

Comment: You haven't said what it's ***meant*** to be doing, so it's not possible to say if it's correct or not.